# Preserve multi-line addresses separated with `<br/>`

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-scripting

- How could I remove extra blank line between address line?   I am
  using Beautifulsoup to **scraping** from a web page.
- I know that `<br/>` generates a new line.  However, If I were to use
  replace to space OR strip():  the few address lines become one line.
  How can I preserve that I still have a few address lines as shown in the expected output below?

**input from html:**

```
<span class="c2">1233/B, LAC II, St. 37/B, Mehmoodabad # 6, (Behind United Bakery),<br />Karachi - 75640<br />Pakistan</span><br />
```

**My code as follows:**

```
if not (item.find('span', class_ = 'c2') is None):
        address = item.find_all('span', class_ = 'c2')
        for a in item.find_all('span', {"class":"c2"}):
            for addr in address:
                print('Before',addr)           
                    if addr.find_all("br"):
                        for a in addr:
                            print('a',a)
                            if '<br/>' in a: 
                                print('a loop',a)
```

**My output for the class(c2) span as follows:**

```
<span class="c2">1233/B, LAC II, St. 37/B, Mehmoodabad # 6, (Behind United Bakery),<br />Karachi - 75640<br />Pakistan</span><br />
```

**Test Output result in the loop of the span as follows**:

```
Before <span class="c2">1233/B, LAC II, St. 37/B, Mehmoodabad # 6, (Behind United Bakery),<br/>Karachi - 75640<br/>Pakistan</span>
a 1233/B, LAC II, St. 37/B, Mehmoodabad # 6, (Behind United Bakery),
a <br/>
a Karachi - 75640
a <br/>
a Pakistan
```

**This causes my current undesirable output result:**
1233/B, LAC II, St. 37/B, Mehmoodabad # 6, (Behind United Bakery),

Karachi - 75640

Pakistan

**Expected output result:**
1233/B, LAC II, St. 37/B, Mehmoodabad # 6,(Behind United Bakery),
Karachi - 75640
Pakistan

Comment: Show examples. Your input, your code, your desired output, and what other code you've tried. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I thought I have shown examples of my input, code, my desired output, and currently bad output.   What did I miss?

Comment: This puzzles me  because it was already there.  Allright, I'll remember the rules.  Thanks.

Comment: You can see from the edit history that no, your examples didn't appear until 13:35Z on June 16th, while you asked the question 1.25h before that. Glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replace_with()` method of a tag object:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''<span class="c2">1233/B, LAC II, St. 37/B, Mehmoodabad # 6, (Behind United Bakery),<br />Karachi - 75640<br />Pakistan</span><br />'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

for br in soup.select('br'):
    br.replace_with('\n')

print(soup.text.strip())
```

Prints:

```
1233/B, LAC II, St. 37/B, Mehmoodabad # 6, (Behind United Bakery),
Karachi - 75640
Pakistan
```

Comment: I originally tried using replace_with function but it does not work well in my case.  This looks simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stripped strings and join

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<span class="c2">1233/B, LAC II, St. 37/B, Mehmoodabad # 6, (Behind United Bakery),<br />Karachi - 75640<br />Pakistan</span><br />
'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
for item in soup.select('.c2'):
    strings = '\n'.join([string for string in item.stripped_strings])
    print(strings)
```

Comment: QHarr, You are a champion because this works after I struggled for a week. Thanks....  SOLVED!

Comment: What did I do wrong to cause stackoverflow.com to block me to ask another question?  I thought I include everything. I don't understand.

Comment: Your current question, which is how I found it, seems good (+1). I don't know the ins and outs of blocking but do know it can occur when too many poorly received questions or perhaps even with too many deleted questions. See info here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

Comment: Oh I got it.  It took me a while to find where to upvote, downvote and helpful icons.  Done!